# Enabling CSA in hostapd

Tags: wifi, linux-device-driver, wireless, hostapd

I am using hostapd_cli(http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hostapd_cli&sektion=8) to interact with my hostapd to change the channel. I am using "chan_switch" command to switch channels.

But this command gets failed with "CSA is not supported" as the error message. Any inputs on how I should go about solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSA is Channel Switch Announcement; which goes inside the beacon to let connected station know that AP is changing the channel. For this things to work device/hw/firmware should able to configure CSA-IE.

In your case, either the device doesn't support CSA or it supports it but have not notified the same in its capabilities.

If you just want to change the channel, which will make stations connected to disconnect first and then reconnect, then you can just change the 'channel' field in hostapd.conf and just reload by 'kill -1'.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: I could change the channel by changing the configuration file, bringing down the interface and launching hostapd with new configuration file. But bringing down the interface and bringing it up takes a lot of time. That is the reason I am going with this approach. I am currently using ath9k driver which supports channel switch. So, I think channel switch command should work. I applied this patch(http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2014-May/030226.html) to support CSA, but it is causing same error. Any inputs on what might be causing this error would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Pawan, Did you try #linux-wireless at irc.freenode.net? You can share the error so that people there can help you.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question, I have tried chan_switch using hostapd_cli without killing hostapd. All you need to do is update your backports version, in my case, I am using backports-4.2.6-1. Just build it and then you can try **chan_switch**   if channel switch is possible it should give OK message else FAIL. I have tried it with more than 10 interfaces at the same time and I was able to change the channel. Attached a screen shot for reference. 
Hope this helps..!![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNDGx.png)

Comment: Hi Anand, can you please share the `hostapd.conf` file that you used, as an edit to your answer? I think that would be very useful for anyone trying to get this working. Also, please mention the WiFi adapter that you used (even the chipset is enough).